# Probability : sick people calling doctors

Tags: probability

A city has 3 doctors and 4 sick people. What is the probability that every doctor is called?

I have no idea how to start thinking about this problem, I was trying to build a probability model for this problem, but I am not sure if this is right and how this will help me formalize (and understand) this apparently simple exercise.

$D = \{d_1,...,d_D\}$ : set of doctors

$M = \{m_1,...,m_M\}$ : set of sick people

$$\Omega = D^M=\{\omega :M\rightarrow D\}$$
$$\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$$
$$P = \text{uniform over } \mathcal{A} $$

With $\omega$ the array describing the doctor of each person.

Comment: Notice that a favorable outcome is a surjective function from a set of four elements to a set of three elements.

Comment: You need some idea of the probability that a sick person will call a doctor.  Also, the time frame needs to be defined.  Instantaneous, within a period of x minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are the only information you are given, then I would assume that a sick patient immediately calls randomly any of the four doctors, and that a doctor can take multiple calls at the same time (receptionists with more than one phone, something fancy like that).

Suppose we have $n$ patients and $k$ doctors. Then with the assumptions it is a Combination-with-repetitions-problem, i.e. "how many ways are there to distribute $n$ objects (patients) into $k$ categories (doctors) without respecting order". The formula for how many possibilities there are is

$$\binom{n+k-1}{n}$$

In your example, there are $n=4$ patients, $k = 3$ doctors, so a total of $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ possibilities. How many possibilities are there to get all 3 doctors called without respecting the order? There are 3 possibilities: Each doctor might be called twice. Then the final probability is $3/15 = 1/5$.